# IOError while trying to read file with ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use `ConfigParser` in the `db_connection.py` file and read the config but `ConfigParser` cannot read my file. I changed the file permissions too but that din't help. Heres my code

```
import ConfigParser
CONFIG = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

if not CONFIG.read('config.ini'):
    raise IOError, 'cannot load config.ini'

DBNAME = CONFIG.get('database', 'name')
```

And my directory structure

```
├── helpers.py
├── logs
├── models
│   ├── config.ini
│   ├── db_connection.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── state-codes.md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is specifying config file path as a relative path. The file will be retrieved from the current working directory.

If you run the program not in the same directory where the config file exist, you should adjust the file path.

For example, if you run the program in the parent directory of the `models` directory, you should specify accordingly:

```
import os

...

if not CONFIG.read(os.path.join('models', 'config.ini')):  # models/config.ini
    raise IOError, 'cannot load config.ini'
```

or you can use `__file__` attribute of the module to make the path relative to the module.

```
import os

config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini')

if not CONFIG.read(config_path):
    raise IOError, 'cannot load config.ini'
```

Both solutions depends on the current working directory. Alternatively you can specify the absolute path. Or make the config file path to be passed from outside (command line argument, environmental variable, ...)

Comment: Got it ! I was indeed running the program from the parent directory to `models` . Anyways I have added a `config.ini` file in the parent directory to `models` and will be using that as the location for my config(which I kinda wanted in the first place) .